# How can I get a solid segmentation from a probability map?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

I trained the network for my data. Once I ran this:
To see the probability map

```
plt.imshow(prob[1], cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

And this is the probability map of `Object 1`:[image]

How can I get the solid segmentation from the probability map (even considering those points with lower probability belonging to the class)?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to give advice without more details of the data, your decision methods/thresholds, etc.  Also, asking "how do I do these standard tasks" makes the question "too broad" on two fronts: too many questions in one posting, and lack of research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the solid segmentation.  One is to use one of the clustering algorithms to define the area of interest.  Perhaps a simple threshold cut-off `p <= (p > threshold)` followed by a density-fill algorithm would suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, how can I estimate the threshold? Thanks